# Django Rest API, how to create post api for 2 model entries, and has foreign key associated to the model

Tags: django, rest, api, serialization, model

I am trying to use DRF Django Rest Framework to create a post API to create entry for 2 models and associate foreign key relationship. How do I accomplish that ?

I have 2 models
- Employee model that OneToOne association with User, and has a ForeignKey Company
- Company model

I want to have a post to create employee model entry and also company model entry and associate the employee to the company. The employee also I want to enter in the User data (username, first_name, last_name, etc).

The following are the code excerpts:

https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employee')
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
```

https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/views.py

```
class EmployeeWithCompanyCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """This class defines the create behavior of our rest api."""
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeWithCompanyCreateSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """Save the post data when creating a new bucketlist."""
        serializer.save()
```

https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercom/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^employee/$', EmployeeWithCompanyCreateView.as_view(), name="create"),
```

https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/serializers.py

```
class EmployeeWithCompanyCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ("id","identity_number", "tel")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution has some thing wrong: the fields list of EmployeeWithCompanyCreateSerializer class is mismatch the fields of  Employee class.
In your question context ,I suggest you write the complicated view  by hand.